# SQL Server 2008 Standard limit resource use per user or database

Tags: sql-server-2008, resources

I need to limit the CPU time used by a single user on SQL Server 2008. Unfortunately this is for Standard Edition, so I can't use Resource Governor.

This user is running data-heavy queries via an Access database linked to one of the databases.  This is causing high enough load on the server that other queries can timeout.

Is there any way to limit CPU usage by user or database in SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition, which is transparent to the queries being run?

What about on the connection from Access?

Answer (score 1):

you could try looking at limiting the amount of cores used by affinity mapping or by the MAXDOP clause in queries if you want more granular control.

Bear in mind that Maxdop will restrict a query to use limited number processors but not the Usage of those processors.Affinity will also restrict the processors but not the usage .
**Only Resource governor can restrict the CPU usage**

more info at :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/9ed64e9a-0af0-4d4d-95e2-709dd9dc68d8/

Comment: I need to be able to enforce this transparently to the user, so it can't be part of the queries.

Comment: there is no way then as stated on my answer "Only Resource governor can restrict the CPU usage"

Comment: What about Windows System Resource Manager?

Comment: it depends by the environment but it is not recommended for SQL

"CPU affinity management through Windows System Resource Manager is not recommended for SQL Server multi-instance management. Instead, use SQL Server's processor affinity settings."
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753280(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. There is only a single instance of SQL so I think this might be the way to go.